# How to fix the array.length changes?

Tags: javascript, arrays

This code requests to introduce a word, saves each letter in an array and then returns it backwards.
My problem is that when I introduce the word "mother" it returns "undefinedrehtom":
So why the first element of the array is "undefined" if in the loop "for" I specified that the array length be such that each element is defined?

```
x = prompt("enter the text:");
var word = new Array();

for (i=0; i<x.length; i++) {
    word[i]= x.charAt(i);
}

for (j=word.length ; j>=0 ; j--) {
    document.write(word[j]);
}
```

Comment: If you're learning, learn to avoid `document.write`. `var s = x.split(''); s.reverse(); console.log(s.join(''))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

array's index starts at 0 so you need to start from array.length - 1 to get last index.

```js
x = prompt("enter the text:");
    var word = new Array();
    
    for (i=0; i<x.length; i++) {
        word[i]= x.charAt(i);
    }
    
    for (j=word.length-1 ; j>=0 ; j--) {
        document.write(word[j]);
    }
```

There is easy way to reverse string,

```js
var x = prompt("enter the text:");
var word = x.split("").reverse().join("");
document.write(word);
```

first, split with ""
then use the array's reverse method and then join them.

Answer (score 0):

You had an error with the loop. Run the second loop from `word.length - 1 to 0` instead of `word.length to 0`

```js
x = prompt("enter the text:");
var word = new Array();

for (i=0; i<x.length; i++) {
    word[i]= x.charAt(i);
}

for (j=word.length - 1 ; j>=0 ; j--) {
    document.write(word[j]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple,

```
x = prompt("enter the text:");
var word = new Array();

for (i=0; i<x.length; i++) {
    word[i]= x.charAt(i);
}

for (j=word.length ; j>=0 ; j--) {  <<--- j value will be length of array in your case
                                          it will be 6
    document.write(word[j]);
}
```

since array starts with 0,

```
word[0] = 'r' 
word[1] = 'e'
word[2] = 'h'
word[3] = 't'
word[4] = 'o'
word[5] = 'm'
word[6] =  ?????  JS doesnt know what it is so it will consider it as undefined.
```

Solution: Like other suggestion lenght-1 will work, or simply using j>0 in for loop also works fine.

Answer (score 0):

j = word.length -1 works because you're trying to access 5th index which doesn't exist and returns undefined on starting of the loop

```
  x = prompt("enter the text:");
var word = new Array();

for (i=0; i<x.length; i++) {
    word[i]= x.charAt(i);
}

for (j=word.length -1 ; j>=0 ; j--) {
    document.write(word[j]);
}
```